# Python periodically remove items from a list

Tags: python, list, element

Say I have a long list with 1000 elements and I want to periodically delete groups of elements based off of two variables.

So for `my_list=[1,2,3,4...1000]`, and `a=5`, `b=7`, I would keep the first 5 elements, delete the next 7, and repeat until the end of the list.

The list will then look like:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14,15,16...]
```

I don't know a or b prior to using them, nor the length of the list, so I'm looking for a general solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your coding attempt so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `enumerate` and taking the `mod` of the index on the sum of `a` and `b`. Filter out values whose mod is less than `a`:

```
l = range(1, 30)
a, b = 5, 7
r = [x for i, x in enumerate(l) if i%(a+b) < a]
print(r)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

<sub>P.S. if you're deleting the next 7, 12 should not be included.</sub>

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I need, thanks!

Also, obviously I'm not great at counting on my fingers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using iterators:

```
import itertools as it

L = list(range(1000))
a, b = 5, 7

mask = it.chain(it.repeat(1, a), it.repeat(0, b))

Result = list(it.compress(L, it.cycle(mask)))
```

[Documentation of the `itertools` standard module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

The cool thing here is that *no intermediate data* is stored in memory, and all the results are generated on-the-fly.